# How to make a magnetic scrolling effect in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a scroll view in my flutter project, it contains 3 containers with each a different height. I want to create an effect where the view snaps to the next or previous `Container` if you scroll.

**Result I want**

[no scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vYcQ.png) -> [first scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg8Tx.png) -> [second scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCuMa.png)

**Code**

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 400,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 500,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 100,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

At the moment I don't have that snapping effect, it's just a normal scrollview.
Using a `PageView` also wouldn't work, because there you need full pages with each maximum height.